# How can I run seleniumbase inside docker?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumbase

I have some seleniumbase code that works correctly normally, but in a Docker container, I get an ElementNotFound Exception, which does not happen when I run locally. Can anyone please help me?

This is how I initialize my driver:

`with SB(uc=True, xvfb=True) as sb:`

This is my dockerfile, very similar to the one provided by seleniumbase github:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

#=======================================
# Install Python and Basic Python Tools
#=======================================
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false -o Acquire::Check-Date=false update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev python-distribute
RUN alias python=python3
RUN echo "alias python=python3" >> ~/.bashrc

#=================================
# Install Bash Command Line Tools
#=================================
RUN apt-get -qy --no-install-recommends install \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    wget \
    curl \
    libxi6 \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    vim \
    xvfb \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#================
# Install Chrome
#================
RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install google-chrome-stable && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#===========================
# Configure Virtual Display
#===========================
RUN set -e
RUN echo "Starting X virtual framebuffer (Xvfb) in background..."
RUN Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
RUN export DISPLAY=:99
RUN exec "$@"

#=======================
# Update Python Version
#=======================
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get -qy --no-install-recommends install python3.8
RUN rm /usr/bin/python3
RUN ln -s python3.8 /usr/bin/python3

#=============================================
# Allow Special Characters in Python Programs
#=============================================
RUN export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
RUN echo "export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8" >> ~/.bashrc

#=====================
# Download WebDrivers
#=====================
RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.34.0/geckodriver-v0.34.0-linux64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf geckodriver-v0.34.0-linux64.tar.gz
RUN chmod +x geckodriver
RUN mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
RUN wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/72.0.3626.69/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN chmod +x chromedriver
RUN mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/

#=======================
# Create Virtual Environment
#=======================
RUN python3 -m pip install virtualenv && \
    python3 -m virtualenv /venv

#============================
# Set Working Directory
#============================
WORKDIR /linkedin_scraper

#=====================
# Copy Source Code
#=====================
COPY ./src ./src
COPY requirements.txt .

#============================
# Install Dependencies
#============================
RUN /venv/bin/python -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

#========================
# Default Command to Run
#========================
#CMD ["/venv/bin/python", "./src/main.py"]
```

Does anyone have experience with this? I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Start by determining what is different between the page source in your local version vs the Docker version. `print(sb.get_page_source())`